# Java or C# to linux based mysql database

Tags: c#, java, mysql, webserver

I'm creating a system for one of my university projects.

Basically, what i'm trying to do is to query a MySQL database stored on a linux web server. I am creating two interfaces, one to register using the a php webpage. The php one is simple enough, and I know what I am doing in regards to that.

The problem I am having is my c# or java (depends which is easiest to do this) application running on my machine, I want either of these applications to query the mySQL server to retrieve data. I know the java or .connectors is not a viable option, so is this possible.

Maybe be running a php script using my application and then parsing the results. Is this possible, and if so any information will be glady accepted.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't the java or .Net connector an option?

Comment: Well, i contacted the web hosting company to ask, and basically I was told No. I've already attempted it using the .net connector, and with no luck. First time i've stepped into this, usually create applications to run on the host machine, without any services.

Comment: The key is that the hosting company will not allow you to install the connectors on their system - that's fine, because they live in your application. In Java, the connector is a jar file bundled with your application, in .net its a DLL. Unless your hosting company is also hosting your java/.net application all they need to do is provide your connection string.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. I thought that was strange, getting that answer back.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the security implications that directly querying MySQL within a standalone application, it's highly unpractical to do such a thing. Anything that can be downloaded can theoretically be decompiled. I highly suggest you use your C# application to WebRequest a PHP script that can complete your queries and echo the results. Then you can use your C# app to interpret this data. It's also much more secure to have specific scripts that do specific things, instead of allowing you to directly enter a query, you instead Web Request your script associated to such a query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is it not secure? PHP suffers from SQL injection the same as any other SQL wrapper ( or direct query ). By interfacing to PHP your killing performance, and not utilizing the plethora of tools available for database access in .net or Java.

Comment: @RobertH Directly embedding your MySQL authentication info can cause anyone who has any knowledge in decompiling to get your MySQL info, and drop your entire table. If correctly constructing and preparing any SQL queries, you will not be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: And adding it to a PHP script allows anyone who hacks the server to have access to the same information. Your point isn't valid in any way. Security will always be flawed as there are, and always will be, people who exploit applications, servers etc. Just because php abstracts the information behind a server doesn't make it any more or less secure then adding the information into into a resource file, be it hibernate, entity framework etc. If you can cite hard facts that calling a PHP script from a java or .net application is more secure then using any ORM or native query, please list it.

Comment: @RobertH Alright, so let me try to explain this better. You want your application to be able to add users and nothing else. If you directly embed your MySQL authentication into your C# app, with decompiling the program you can then query anything. So I can decompile the C#, and query: DROP TABLE users. However, if you use a PHP script, that gets the information from a GET request and then queries to add that specified user to the database, correctly using PDO and binding params. You're now secure. They can add users but cannot do anything else. Your move Robert.

Comment: Again, back up your statements with a reputable source. If your argument was a legit concern then we wouldn't have JDBC,Hibernate, Entity Framework or any other ORM or native database access method, instead we would have a library to make a call to some PHP script located on some server. I can claim that elephants are purple with pink polkadots and roam the artic tundra, but it doesn't make it true.

Comment: I'm not going to be bothered to find a reputable website to state something that I know is true. If you're really concerned about this, please make a program that connects to a database and can add users, and I'll kindly drop the table to prove to you this. However, if there's a PHP script which all it can do is do the INSERT INTO query, something like dropping a table is impossible